# Correlation data in separate variables in R -- stragegies for analysis?

Tags: r, dataframe

First time post, thanks for your patience. In this sample data frame, there a 4 pairs of data points I want to evaluate.

To get you oriented: variable letters "a" and "b" represent 2 different methods used to measure 2 different structures "RUPV" and "RLPV". So in this df I want to compare 4 pairs of data.

- Row 1 represents a single comparison (RUPV, measured using methods "a" and "b")
- Row 2 represents 2 comparisons (RUPVa with RUPVb, RLPVa with RLPVb. No other comparisons)
- Row 3 is also a single comparison, this time for RLPV
- Rows 4 and 5 are missing data, and would not be used for analysis. But it represents what I'm dealing with in the original data set.

```
df1 <- data.frame(RUPVa = c(1,2,NA,NA,NA), 
                    RLPVa = c(NA,3,4,NA,NA), 
                    RUPVb = c(1,2,NA,NA,5), 
                    RLPVb = c(NA,3,4,NA,NA))
```

Question: Even though the values are distributed differently in the df, I want to collapse the 4 pairs of data for analysis, which includes scatterplots and correlations (regardless of the structure). Should I code using these original columns, or is there a way to bring all the pairs together into 2 new variables (say "a" and "b")?

- I've tried commands like `pivot_longer()` but I don't know how to merge the random pairs into just 2 columns, one for method "a" and one for "b".

If you want to use my actual column names there are 8 total,listed below. Within the names, the characters "mean" = method "a", and "direct" = method "b". For a given row, the values will be randomly present or missing. I have not included them here, but can if needed.

rupv_mean_27
direct_rupv_pre
rlpv_mean_32
direct_rlpv_pre
lupv_mean_37
direct_lupv_pre
llpv_mean_42
direct_llpv_pre

Comment: Can you show  the form of your expected result for `df1`?

Comment: @PeaceWang something like this: `df2 <- data.frame(a=c(1:4),
                  b=c(1:4))`

Comment: @Ben If there aren't pairs of values (row 5 should have a numeric value for RUPVb and RUPVa), then I consider that missing. For your second question, yes-- my actual dateset has many more columns and rows, but the pattern of periodic missingness will be similar. Please let me know if I need to clarify more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but this may help out. I would add a column to indicate the row number, since you are considering pairs of values within a row. You can use `pivot_longer` to make the data tidy - with each row an observation.

Using `pivot_longer` you can put your data into long form, which will be more [tidy](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf). The arguments include:

- `cols` which are columns to pivot (in this case, all columns except `rn`.
- `names_pattern` which is a regex pattern (or regular expression) to separate the columns into two groups. The first group is `\\w+` which is one or more word characters, like `RUPV` or `RLPV`. The second group is `a|b` which is the letter "a" or "b". The `$` at the end is the end of the string.
- `names_to` which has the names of the two new columns created for the matching two groups: `structure` and `method`.

---

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c("structure", "method"), names_pattern = "(\\w+)(a|b)$")

      rn structure method value
   <int> <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>
 1     1 RUPV      a          1
 2     1 RLPV      a         NA
 3     1 RUPV      b          1
 4     1 RLPV      b         NA
 5     2 RUPV      a          2
 6     2 RLPV      a          3
 7     2 RUPV      b          2
 8     2 RLPV      b          3
 9     3 RUPV      a         NA
10     3 RLPV      a          4
11     3 RUPV      b         NA
12     3 RLPV      b          4
13     4 RUPV      a         NA
14     4 RLPV      a         NA
15     4 RUPV      b         NA
16     4 RLPV      b         NA
17     5 RUPV      a         NA
18     5 RLPV      a         NA
19     5 RUPV      b          5
20     5 RLPV      b         NA
```

---

You can then remove missing data. First, `filter` and remove `NA` in the `value` column. Then, for each structure/row combination only include structure/rn combinations when pairs of values are present. Finally, you can use `pivot_wider` to put into the desired wide form.

Here is the entire code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c("structure", "method"), names_pattern = "(\\w+)(a|b)") %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(rn, structure) %>%
  filter(n() == 2) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(rn, structure), names_from = method, values_from = value)
```

**Output**

```
     rn structure     a     b
  <int> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 RUPV          1     1
2     2 RUPV          2     2
3     2 RLPV          3     3
4     3 RLPV          4     4
```

Comment: This is helpful. I'll have to stare at the piping code and link that up to the steps you described in your answer.  I think the key thing for me to apply this to my actual data lies in the `names_pattern` argument. 1) can you clarify "(\\w+)", as far as what that is searching for?  2) if I have additional questions about string pattern matching, do I post that as a new question?

Comment: @BrianS See edited answer. The `names_pattern` uses a regex pattern. The `\\w+` includes one or more word characters. In this case, would be "RUPV" or "RLPV". The second group matches the letter "a" or "b". Also added "$" to indicate end of string. Let me know if you have more questions. You always have the option to post another question about regex patterns and string matching. I'm also happy to try to answer if I can as well. It will help to know what your columns names are in your dataset.

Comment: Edited my question to add my actual column names (guess I should've led with that). @Ben While trying to adapt your code I'm struggling with regex. Suggestions on how to match the names?

Comment: One option is just to rename your column names with `names(df1) <- c(...)`. Another is to use `names_sep` instead of some regex. For example, if you remove the "direct" part of the column names, you could try `pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c("structure", "method"), names_sep = "_")` and that will separate based on underscore. Or, if you want to preserve your column names and use a more complex regex, you can do that too - I can provide something later when i have a moment...